# Why a infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ is uncountable?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Why a infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ is uncountable?

I think its just simple linear Algebra,but i just cannot see it.Please help

Comment: Forget that; I was wrong.

Comment: @Arthur was there some other problem in your mind?

Comment: I forgot that the direct sum also was infinite dimensional. The diagonal argument doesn't work in that case since the witness you create in that proof isn't certain to be an element of the vector space.

Comment: Actually, this is not true. Spaces of countable infinite dimension over $F_2$ are not uncountable.

Comment: @mathematician, what you say is not true: countably infinite vector spaces over a field are all (linearly) isomorphic. In fact, dimension (as a cardinal ) is still a complete invariant. The direct product of infinite-countably many copies of $ F $ has dimension $2^{\aleph_0} $, not $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is false.

Let $V  = \bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bbb F_2$. Then $V$ is infinite-dimensional over $\Bbb F_2$.

Let $A_n = \{ (a_j)\in V: a_j=0$ for $j \geq n\}$. Then each $A_n$ is finite (with cardinality $2^{n-1}$). Moreover $V = \bigcup_n A_n$. Thus $V$ is countable.

Comment: This is correctly a counterexample, and in fact can be generalized to any countable field. +1

Comment: The same example rendered without much notation:  the set of all polynomials in a single variable with coefficients from $\mathbf{F}_2$ is isomorphic to Shalop's  example. Actually polynomial rings over the rationals or any finite field in any finite number of variables is also countable.

Comment: The set of all algebraic numbers is a countably infinite dimensional  vector space over the rationals.  And algebraic numbers are countable.

Answer (score 2):

A quick exposition of the general case: a set $\mathcal B$ of linearly independent generators of a $k$-vector space $V$ gives a bijective function ($k$-linear isomorphism) of $V$ onto the set ($k$-vector space) $$k^{(\mathcal B)}:=\left\{f:\mathcal B\to k\text{ s.t. for all but finitely many }b\in\mathcal B,\ f(b)=0\right\}$$

So, with some cardinality theory you have the formula:

\begin{align}\# V&=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }\dim V=0\\(\#k)^{\dim V}&\text{if }\max(\#k,\dim V)<\aleph_0\\ \max(\#k,\dim V)&\text{if }\max(\#k,\dim V)\ge\aleph_0\wedge \dim V\ne0\\
\end{cases}=\\&=\min\left(\max(\#k,\dim V),(\#k)^{\dim V}\right)\end{align}

In your case, $\#V=\min(\max(2,\aleph_0),2^{\aleph_0})=\min(\aleph_0,2^{\aleph_0})=\aleph_0$.

**On the bijective function:** Define the map 
\begin{align}H:k^{(\mathcal B)}&\to V\\ H(f)&:= \sum\limits_{b\in \mathcal B, f(b)\ne 0} f(b)b\end{align}

Since $\mathcal B$ generates $V$, $H$ is surjective: in fact, for *dinstinct* $b_1,\cdots,b_m\in\mathcal B$, you have $a_1b_1+\cdots a_mb_m=H(g)$, with $g(b)=\begin{cases}a_i&\text{if }\exists i,\ b=b_i\\0&\text{if }\forall i,b\ne b_i\end{cases}$

Since $\mathcal B$ is a set of linearly independent elements, the function is injective. In fact, $$H(f)=H(g)\implies\sum_{f(b)\ne 0}f(b)b=\sum_{g(b')\ne0}g(b')b'\implies\\ \implies\sum_{f(b)\ne0,\, g(b)=0}f(b)b-\sum_{f(s)=0,\, g(s)\ne0}g(s)s+\sum_{f(t)\ne0,\,g(t)\ne0}(f(t)-g(t))t=0$$
Since a null linear combination of elements of $\mathcal B$ must have all coefficients null, the realtion above yields that:

- the first two sums range over an empty set of indices, i.e. that $f(b)=0\iff g(b)=0$ for all $b\in\mathcal B$;
- as soon as $f(b)\ne0$, $f(b)-g(b)=0$, i.e. $f(b)=g(b)$.

Putting together: $f=g$.

Comment: Thank you,i understand it now!(+1 ofc)